# how to drag a zoomed-image inside a View Pager without scrolling to the next page in flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart

how to drag a zoomed-image inside a ViewPager without scrolling to the next page in flutter?
I'm using photo_view library to show images

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this was resolved using the `PhotoViewGallery.builder` from the [photo_view](https://pub.dev/packages/photo_view) package